# Forcing gedit to recognize .kv files

Tags: 18.04, gedit, mime-type, syntax-highlighting

On Ubuntu, the language that defines syntax highlighting for kivy layout files is installed by default (or added automatically when installing kivy). The problem is, in gedit, I have to manually select the language for each .kv file in order to get syntax highlighting. I've edited /etc/mime.types to include the following line

```
text/x-kivy                 .kv
```

but this has not solved the problem. Can someone more knowledgeable than me explain how to make this connection?

Answer (score 1):

First of, You have to download the file "kv.lang" from the address:
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView/LanguageDefinitions

Secondly, you have to copy the downloaded file to the appropriate folder which is
" /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/." 
After donwloading the file you can use the following command:

```
    $ sudo cp /yourDownloadLocation/kv.lang /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/
```

Comment: I already have a file 'kv.lang' in /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/, and syntax highlighting for kivy works in Gedit if I enable it on a per file basis, but what I don't understand is why the syntax highlighting does not work automatically for .kv files the way it does for every other type of file, such as .py.